# Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'Bool'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, mobile-application

In below code , error is coming like this. error is coming like

> "Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'Bool']"

```
private func saveImages(){

        let document = try !FileManager.default.url(for:.documentDirectory , in : .userDomainMask , appropriateFor:  nil , create: true) //[error is = Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'Bool']
        print (document)

        let imgUrl = document.appendingPathComponent("1.jpg" , isDirectory : true)
        print(imgUrl.path)

        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: imgUrl.path){
            do{
                try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named : "1.jpg") !)?.write (to :imgUrl)
                print("image added successfully")
            }catch{
                print("image not added")
            }

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a subtle but crucial typo.

Replace

```
try !FileManager
```

With

```
try! FileManager
```

Comment: That was a nice catch! Should solve it